# Вырезать вхождения (несколько) из строки средствами PHP?

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста как вырезать вхождения из строки средствами PHP

```
// Исходная строка
MINI «ДУЭТ» – 3000 р. MINI «SABAI» – 3500 р.

// Нужно
Вырезать от "–" до "р."
Поставить разделитель ";"

// Должно стать
MINI «ДУЭТ»; MINI «SABAI»
```

Comment: Вам могут помочь [функции для работы со строками](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.strings.php), [регулярные выражения](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pcre.pattern.php). Уже что-то попробовали из этого? С чем возникли трудности?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vkq0VE/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = 'MINI «ЦЕЛЕБНЫЙ ДУЭТ» – 3000 р. MINI «SABAI SABAI» – 3500 р.';
$str = preg_replace("/\s–\s*\d+\s*р\./", ";", $args);
$str = substr($str,0,-1);
print_r($str);
echo '<br>';
die();
```